# How do I Get and Set a field in a Onedrive embedded Excel sheet?

Tags: javascript, excel, onedrive

In JS, how do I Get or Set a field in a Onedrive embedded Excel sheet?

I'm really just looking for the any simple solution for it.

History:
At present, I'm using the Javascript setup for adding the project, as found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh315812(v=office.14).aspx).

I'm also using this script to get the sheet, once it is loaded.

```
var a = Ewa.EwaControl.getInstances().getItem(0);
var b = a.getActiveWorkbook();
var c = b.getActiveSheet();
```

But with the active sheet, I don't know how to get the cells or set them.

If you know how to finish the code I have, great.  If you know another solution, that would also be fine.

- Thanks.

Comment: I found out how to READ values here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee588949.aspx - basically get range just creates a range object, then using an async call, it calls out to the server and grabs the value.

Comment: Now All I need is how to SET a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Get/Set the cell data, use the Async call from c (the selected range)

GET:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee588949.aspx

SET:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee588957.aspx